# Multiple WHERE EXISTS with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to use a multiple `WHERE EXISTS` with CQL/Cypher?
Based on a OpenStreetMap dataset, so something like this (not allowed):

```
MATCH path=((node_osm)-[t:TAGS]->(node_addr))
WHERE EXISTS(node_osm.`lat`) AND WHERE EXISTS(node_osm.`lon`)
RETURN path
```

If I use this:

```
WHERE EXISTS(node_osm.`lat`) AND (node_osm.`lon`)
```

I get this error message:
`Don't know how to treat that as a predicate: 4.4732509`

How can I use a multiple `WHERE EXISTS` with CQL/Cypher in Neo4j 3.0.4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
WHERE EXISTS(...) AND EXISTS(...)
```